# php nested while loop not functioning correctly

Tags: php, while-loop

I am attempting to get a nested loop to retrieve information from a database and arrange it by type.  It retrieves the data but arranges it weird, kinda like this:

```
                         Crawler Dozer

                           Excavator
```

```
|Unit  |Type         |Year|  Make       |   Model  |   Engine |
---------------------------------------------------------------
|D8-1  |Crawler Dozer|0000| Caterpillar |   D8K    |   D342   |
```

So on and so forth.....
It skips the title for the 'Crawler Dozer' and puts it under 'Excavator'.  I have reworked the code several different ways, but still get the same result.

This is my code:

```
if(mysqli_query($conn, "select * from etypes") != null){
  $etype_list=mysqli_query($conn, "select * from etypes order by name asc");
  while($types_list=mysqli_fetch_array($etype_list)){
    $cur_type = $types_list['name'];
    if(record_exists ("equipment", "type", "{$cur_type}")){
      ?>
      <center><h3><?php echo $types_list['name'];?></h3></center>
      <table id="ListTables">
      <tr align=bottom>
      <th width="10%">Unit</th>
      <th width="20%">Type</th>
      <th width="5%">Year</th>
      <th width="15%">Make</th>
      <th width ="5%">Model</th>
      <?php
      if($types_list['selfpowered'] == 1){
        ?>
        <th width="15%">Engine</th>
        <?php
      }
      if($types_list['highwayuse'] == 1){
        ?>
        <th width="15%">Plate</th>
        <?php
      }
      ?>
      </tr>
      <?php
      $equipment_list=mysqli_query($conn, "select * from equipment where type='{$cur_type}' order by unitid asc");
      while($unit_list=mysqli_fetch_array($equipment_list)){
        ?>
        <tr class="clickable " onclick="window.location='equipinfo.php?id=<?php echo $unit_list['unitid']?>'">
        <td align=center><?php echo $unit_list['unitid']; ?></td>
        <td align=center><?php echo $unit_list['type']; ?></td>
        <td align=center><?php echo $unit_list['year']; ?></td>
        <td align=center><?php echo $unit_list['make']; ?></td>
        <td align=center><?php echo $unit_list['model']; ?></td>
        <?php
        if($types_list['selfpowered'] == 1){
          ?>
          <td align=center><?php echo $unit_list['engine']; ?></td>
          <?php
        }
        if($types_list['highwayuse'] == 1){
          ?>
          <td align=center><?php echo $unit_list['plate']; ?></td>
          <?php
        }
        ?>
        </tr>
        <?php
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have tried to use a do-while instead.  I put error checking echo text in the code after each while and it placed them right after each other once.

Comment: How can I work around that? Should it have stored the array in the variable?

Comment: I switched the nested one to mysqli_fetch_assoc and it still does the same thing.  It works perfectly as it does not repeat data and creates each Title, but everything is ofset.  It skips the First title and places it under the second and I can not see how it is able to do it.  By the time it comes back on the while loop it should have the new type and plugging it into the next set of equipment, but it doesn't.

Comment: ok, so I added the Title to the top of the table and it fixed it .... :@